# c++ multiple smart pointers allocation cause crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++, smart-pointers

The *maxPointers* value may need to be different for your system, but allocating many *unique_ptr*s causes this application to crash and burn. Removing the definition of *s* and the *cin* operation gives some more room for pointer allocation.

Using MSVC 2015.

So, why does it crash and how to avoid it?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main(int argn, const char*argv[])
{
    int maxPointers = 37900;
    vector<unique_ptr<string>> pointerHolder;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxPointers; i++)
    {
        pointerHolder.push_back(make_unique<string>("pointer " + i));
    }
    cout << "done creating "<< maxPointers << " pointers" << endl;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxPointers; i++)
    {
        pointerHolder.at(i).release();
    }
    pointerHolder.clear();
    cout << "done releasing " << maxPointers << " pointers" << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: what is the result of `"pointer " + i` ? you probably meant `"pointer " + std::to_string(i)`

Comment: Garbage. Yes, that's what I meant. Works now, thanks.

Comment: `("pointer " + i);`  C++ is not Java or JavaScript.  This does not concatenate strings.

Comment: BTW, why not use `std::vector<std::string>` directly ?

Comment: It's just a test case. I'm coming from a scripting background as it can be seen and I'm trying to familiarize myself with and understand some c++ features.

Comment: Get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)! Learning C++ by trial-and-error is akin to dancing blindfolded close to a cliff. C++ contains undefined behavior, i.e. expressions that the compiler is allowed to translate into "fry your harddisk". In the best case your test case will crash, but it might also appear to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash you encounter is because you build strings from garbage that results from call `"pointer " + i`. If you intend to concatenate literal `"pointer"` with an integer, then you'd need to convert that integer to `std::string` with [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) first:

```
make_unique<string>("pointer " + to_string(i));
//                               ~~~~~~~~~~~^
```